# Write and modify string into variable in a single step

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like to save some code but haven't found a way to save the content of an array element into a variable and modify this string at the same time:

```
$state = $displayContents[$ln+6];
$state =~ s/(.+State.+)([ON|OFF]LINE)/$2/;
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
$state = $displayContents[$ln+6] =~ s/(.+State.+)([ON|OFF]LINE)/$2/;
```

Is there a way to save some code and do both steps in one line?

Comment: Could you supply some sample input? I think your regex is wrong - `[ON|OFF]LINE` doesn't match 'ONLINE' it matches `FLINE` or `NLINE` or `OLINE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first off - "saving code" is a false economy. Concise compact code is NOT better. The computer doesn't care, plain text bytes are cheap, and future programmers don't want to be having to break their brain parsing your code when they're trying to fix it.

That said - you can do this by using a match regular expression.

Based on your regexp:

```
my ( $state) = ( $displayContents[$ln+6] =~ m/.+State.+([ON|OFF]LINE)/ )
```

Although, I think that pattern might actually be wrong as it stands it matches:

```
State NLINE
State OLINE
State FLINE
```

I am assuming you're looking for the word `ONLINE` or `OFFLINE`?

In which case you'd need:

```
my ( $state ) = ( $displayContents[$ln+6] =~ m/State ((?:ON|OFF)LINE)/ );
```

This works because if you test a pattern match in a scalar context, it returns a true/false result. If you do it in a list context, it returns an array containing all the capture `()` results.

We use `(:?` as a non-capturing bracket, because otherwise our pattern would return `("ONLINE", "ON")` and discard the second result. Harmless, but redundant and a source of future gotchas.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I think we can argue about the compact code regarding those variables. Your example is exactly what I was looking for and your assumption was correct, made a regex error there.

Comment: Yes. It's a style point rather than a technical one. My _opinion_ is that clarity is the most essential thing that code should have - and the advantage of perl is you can format your code to optimise for clarity. If taking multiple lines does that, then that's all good - I've often taken an assignment, followed by several 'transform' patterns on separate lines just to make clear what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. Try this instead:

```
( my $state = $displayContents[$ln+6] ) =~ s/(.+State.+)([ON|OFF]LINE)/$2/;
```

`=~` takes precedence over `=`, See [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity).